How can I get the Thevenin equivalent of this circuit?


I need to do this circuit but I can't do it properly, I don't know if I done well the nodes analysis, the answers are Rth= 79.66 ohm and Vth= 5.29 V, thanks for your help.

A very warm welcome to the site. Have corrected your question title. 'Thevenin' comes from Mr Thevenin. It's not 'Thevening', as if its been Thevened :-)

Notice that V1 will short-out  R5 and R1 resitors as well.

Elisa, Are you required to solve this in some particular way? Or are you allowed to use any approach that gets you the right answer? You mention nodal. Which is why I ask.

@periblesis No it is not necessary do it with nodal.

@Elisa Then I added a small note to help out. Otherwise, I think Andy has also done a lot to help you.

To find the Thevenin voltage at A and B you should try and simplify things.
The first thing you should note is this: -

This means that the circuit reduces to: -

And, the 9 volt source and the 5 volt source combine to be a single 14 volt source in series with R4.
You can also short out R7 because it is in series with a current source and plays no role: -

Can you take it from here?

oops fixing thanks @periblepsis

I will try do it by that way, thank for your answer Andy aka

Added my +1. ;)

You missed just one detail in getting the right Thevenin resistance:

\$R_1\$, \$R_2\$, \$I_1\$, \$V_2\$, and \$R_5\$ can't alter anything as seen from A and B. What this subnet may alter is the current in \$V_1\$. But otherwise \$V_1\$ spans across that subnet and therefore bypasses it from the global perspective of terminals A and B.
Since you can use any method to get the Thevenin voltage, then I think Andy has set you up for that. You can either Nortonize the \$14\:\text{V}\$ source and the \$100\:\Omega\$ resistor, add that current source to \$I_2\$ and then Thevenize the resulting Norton. Or use some other approach.
The voltage at B will be more positive than the voltage at A, though. So be careful about specifying the resulting Thevenin voltage.

Thank you for your answer periblepsis

The Thevenin voltage \$V_{th}\$ would be negative as the Norton current source generated with the 14V voltage source  when added to 2A current source becomes a 0.6A current source towards ground.After this, convert the Norton current source back to a Thevenin voltage source.The Thevenin resistance is (82 || (2200+100+500)) which is 79.66Ω. Be slightly careful in your circuit analysis.
